# Capturar mudanças que foram renderizadas com state em vueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Estou renderizando os dados que estão em um `state` no `vuex` em alguns inputs que ficam espalhados pela tela; sei que não consigo utilizar o mesmo método de um "model" (two-way-databiding) para alterar o valor de um state pois o mesmo precisa de um `commit` para ser alterado.

Como posso pegar todos os valores do input de uma maneira mais facil para efetuar o commit para que o `state` seja alterado?

atualmente eu coloquei um `ref` em cada input mas isso esta muito verboso e acredito que eu esteja me equivocando em fazer isso e que existe uma maneira mais adequada:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-form-input :value="order.payer" ref="payer"></b-form-input>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
...
...
computed: mapGetters({
    // order preenche os inputs com por exemplo: "order.id" e "order.payer"
    order: 'getOrderObject',
}),
...
...
methods: {
    save () {
        let inputs = {
            payer: this.$refs.payer.$el.value // muito verboso :(
        }
    }
}
...
...
```

Comment: Você não pode simplesmente alterar o objeto order e depois dar commit dele de volta? Outra opção é ter algo como uma array/objeto de inputs no data do componente, e usar isso com v-model no template. O método save só precisaria pegar essa lista de inputs para dar commit.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu pensei em "clonar" o state de `order` e depois enviar um commit.

Comment: Nem sei se precisa clonar

Comment: acredito que eu não consiga alterar o objeto `order` porque ele representa meu `state` e não posso alterado sem fazer commit

Answer (score 0):

Antes de apresentar uma alternativa para seu caso, segue uma informação que justifica a maneira como vou fazer.

*Vuex* tem uma configuração chamada **strict mode**, que pode ser `true` ou `false`, esta configuração com valor `false` permite que você faça alterações do `state` fora dos `muntations` da `store`. Leia mais sobre o **strict mode** e por que ele não é recomendado em modo de produção [aqui](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/strict.html).

Esse jeito é baseado na documentação do vue, nuxt, minha experiência e mais alguns links que vou deixar abaixo.

Esse método eu uso em uma [estrutura do framework nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure), usei como exemplo um `state` de usuário com a propriedade para o nome.
Baseado na documentação do vue, vuex, minha experiência e alguns links que vou colocar lá embaixo, basicamente o `input` recebe o valor do `getter` e ao apertar enter você dispara um `actions` como método que pega o valor do campo e atualiza objeto `user`, usando [spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32372430/7883899) pra fazer merge, no `state` da store.

Se tiver dúvida comenta!

*index.vue*

```
<template>
  <input type="text" :value="user.name" @keyup.enter="updateName($event)">
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    methods: {
      ...mapActions({
        updateName: 'updateName'
      })
    },
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
        user: 'getUser'
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

*store/index.js*

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import getters from './getters'
import actions from './actions'
import mutations from './mutations'

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      user: {
        name: ''
      }
    },
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
  })
}

export default createStore
```

*store/getters.js*

```
const getters = {
  getUser(state) {
    return state.user
  }
}

export default getters
```

*store/actions.js*

```
const actions = {
  updateName({ commit, getters }, event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    let name = event.target.value

    commit('SET_USER', { name })
  }
}

export default actions
```

*store/mutations.js*

```
const mutations = {
  SET_USER(state, user) {
    state.user = { ...state.user, ...user }
  }
}

export default mutations
```

links
[Vuex Store pela documentação do Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store)
[Evento ao apertar enter no Vue.js](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Modificadores-de-Teclado)